# Copy From Azure Blob to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: powershell, azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that copy recursively from Azure Blob to Amazon AWS S3 Bucket But without much success.

Can someone help me please ?

```
$container_name = @("<ContainerItemName>")
$connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<AccountName>;AccountKey=<AccountKey>'

$storage_account = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString $connection_string

$S3Bucket = "<BucketName>"

foreach ($container_item in $container_name)
{
    $blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container_item -Context $storage_account

    foreach ($blob in $blobs)
    {
        $item = Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $container_item -Blob $blob.Name -Context $storage_account
        Write-S3Object -BucketName $S3Bucket -KeyPrefix $container_item\ -Folder $item -Force
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't played with AWS PowerShell Cmdlets (so I may be wrong) but taking a quick look at their documentation [`here`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-s3-upload-object.html), I think you would need to save the blob on your local computer first and then specify that path in your `Write-S3Object` cmdlet `-File` parameter.

Downloading Azure Blob to a directory:

```
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container containername -Blob blob -Destination C:\test\
```

Assuming the blob's name is blob.png, uploading it to S3:

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName $S3Bucket -KeyPrefix $container_item\ -File "C:\test\blob.png" -Force
```

Comment: I know this way but I need it to copy directly from one to another (Blob to S3).

Comment: From what I understand about S3, I don't thing it is possible to create an S3 object this way. You would need to download the blob to your computer and then upload that file in S3.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Azure Storage Data movement library. You can download the sample code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/tree/master/samples/S3ToAzureSample. Following article contains more information on Data movement library: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-storage-data-movement-library-preview-2/